# Is Deconvolution possible for video in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I want to film a batter swinging at a baseball, but the bat is blurry.  The video is 30 fps.

Through research I have found that deconvolution seems to be the way to minimize motion blur, but I have no idea if or how I can implement it in my iOS app post processing.

I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction like how to apply a deconvolution algorithm in iOS or what I might need to do...or if it is even possible.  I imagine it takes some processing power.

Any suggestions at all are welcome...

Thanks, this is driving me crazy...

Comment: This is not a trivial problem, and is the subject of a lot of research. See this question on Signal Processing: [How do I remove motion blur?](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/132/how-do-i-remove-motion-blur). If you can come up with an appropriate kernel to work against your video frames, you could apply that as an OpenGL ES fragment shader for fastest processing. I have several convolution shaders in my GPUImage ( https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage ) framework, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I did look at this question and your framework earlier today before I asked the question.  I guess I do not know anything about doing this.  I don't know exactly what a kernel is at this point even.  In my research I did not find any clear cut answer either.  I will see what I can find out about creating a kernel, but any further help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and talks with developers about deconvolusion on iOS (Thanks to Brad Larson for taking the time to give me detailed information) I am confident that it is not possible and/or not worth the time.  If the hardware can handle the computations (No guarantee) it would be EXTREMELY slow and consume much of the device's battery.  I have also been told it could take months to implement the algorithms...if it is possible at all.

Here is the response I received from Apple...

> Deconvolution algorithms are generally difficult to implement and can be very computationally intensive. I suggest you starting with a simple sharpening technique. Depending on the amount of the motion blur in your video, it might just suffice.
>
> The sharpen filters, including CISharpenLuminance and CIUnsharpMask, are now available in iOS 6, so it is moderately easy to test them out.
>
> Core Image Filter Reference
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html
>
> Core Image sample code from this year's WWDC session 511 "Core Image Techniques". It's called "Attempt3". This sample demonstrates best practices for applying CIFilter's to a live video taken by the iPhone/iPad camera. You may download the session video from the following page: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/.

Just wanted to pass this information along.