# Is there any way to un blur the CIGaussianblur filter and get the original un blurred image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, blur, cifilter

I am uploading a blurred image to my server and download it later on in my app. I then need to un blur that original image. The blur filter is the cigaussianblur filter.

I know I can store the original image along with the blurred image on my server but if I can un blur the blurred image, this would be the better option for me. Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50140306/4124168

Answer (score 0):

> but if I can un blur the blurred image, this would be the better option for me

Well, you can't. The information is lost from the image. If you want to keep the original information, as you rightly say, store the original image. (That, by the way, is how iPhoto / Photos works; it stores the original image along with any edited versions of that image. That is what makes editing operations undoable.)

Comment: Okay that's good to know! I'll stick with storing the original. Thanks matt!

Comment: The information is not lost. It can be undone. This is not the case where you want to create a crisp image from a low resolution photo. And it isn't the case where the blur originates from poor lenses or poorly focused real-world photography. Instead it's a simple mathematical algorithm for blurring that can be reverted. Having said that, you're still better off with storing the original image.

Answer (score 0):

CIGaussianBlur is a convolution operation. It can be undone with a deconvolution operation using the same kernel. However, deconvolution requires far more computing power than convolution and there is now direct support for it in iOS.

- [Convolution in iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vImage/ConvolutionOperations/ConvolutionOperations.html)
- [Deconvolution in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution)
- [Apple thinks deconvolution on iOS is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13236251/413337)